# how to make angular 4/6 faster in loading?

Tags: angular, performance, lazy-loading

In **Angular 6**, I have created lazy module and it takes a-lot time to load while routing.

Is there any way to create faster web application in **angular 6** ?

Comment: How much is a lot? And how big is the module then? Maybe you can check if you can reduce the size.

Comment: some chunks are larger around 450 KB because of external libraries. Is there any possibilities to reduce than that ... i have built with " ng build --prod " whole project is about 3.2 MB  and after compressing 1.2MB and even it is slow.

Comment: The only way I can think of with only what you've said is using a service worker so your users don't have to download the whole app again and again. That said, first load will still be as long as before. Otherwise if you want to try to optimize your bundle you may try to dig into it and see if anything that should be tree shaked is still here for example. Use source map explorer to dig into your bundles.

Comment: the main problem is sometimes.. with CTRL+F5, it loads faster like 1 sec to load ... some times it is slower  5 sec.. Is it related with server or angular problem ? Most of the times it takes 5 sec to load ..!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If loading a module while navigating takes too much time, you could consider eagerly preloading modules instead. What this does is load your main application module first and display your view, and in the background load all the other modules even before you navigate to them.

You can use the following RouterModule configuration to make that work:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
})
```

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading) for more information.

Comment: if you have a large project It's not good to use PreloadAllModules because at the first time It takes much time