# How to make angular 6 faster in loading below 2 seconds

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading

> Hi, I have implemented following below as

```
  1. lazy loading with CustomPreloadingStrategy module.
  2. Gulp Compress src img folders.
  3. Enable Gzip compression.
```

1. **If I cleared browser then initial load page vendor and
   main js file size 2.4MB and 223 KB.**

> Again after initial page load then why it's still load initial application module more than 8
>   seconds , I want to figure out below 2 seconds.

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "cfch",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "gulp && ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prebuild": "gulp"
  },
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
}
```

**app-routing-module.ts**

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: '../components/multiple-companies/multiple-companies.module#MultipleCompaniesModule',
      data: { preload: true }   // Custom property we will use to track what route to be preloaded
    },  
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
        preloadingStrategy: CustomPreloadingStrategy
    })
    ],
    providers: [ CustomPreloadingStrategy ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**CustomPreloadingStrategy.ts**

```
export class CustomPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      return load();
    } else {
      return Observable.of(null);
    }   }
```

- I added multiple companies (module, router, components).

**Example:**
**MultipleCompaniesRoutingModule.ts**

```
const multipleCompaniesRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
      path: '',
    component: MultipleCompaniesComponent,
    children: [ 
          {
          path: '',
            component: CfchDataTableComponent
            }  
        ]
    }   
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(multipleCompaniesRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class MultipleCompaniesRoutingModule { }
```

**angular.json**

```
   {
 "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with `CustomPreloadingStrategy` method?

Comment: I updated my post.also i tried this reference link too :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434416/how-to-make-angular-4-6-faster-in-loading

Comment: Thanks. Please add the `MultipleCompaniesModule` too

Comment: Can you show us the top part of your picture?

Comment: Updated my post.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the loading/response times of your application building it with the --prod --aot flags? 
Before building check if you have the optmization flags set to true in angular.json configurations/release/optimization

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement a service worker . it will make your page load faster .

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro.